# Can queued messages be moved between Postfix servers?

Tags: email, postfix

My scenario is that I have an air gapped machine for keysigning. I was given some code that generates emails for individuals to receive their signed keys but I would like to keep this machine off any network. I set up Postfix on this machine to put all email into the hold queue. Now I'm trying to figure out a way to inject these emails onto my networked server with Postfix properly set up to deliver mail. I've tried moving the email into the hold directory and queueing them with `sudo postsuper -r ALL`. It says the messages were queued, but they never get delivered. Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, I ended up accomplishing my goal by using `postcat` to dump all the queued emails into separate files, copied those to the new server and injected them into Postfix using `sendmail -t`. The `-t` flag instructs sendmail to use the headers from the file instead of specifying the sender and recipient as command line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish all this with a single command, and send the message directly to another server via ssh. I also edited the `From` field, setting it to the one from `msg_id_in_queue` (taken from enviromental variables, otherwise):

```
postcat -bhq <msg_id_in_queue> | ssh user@server2 "sendmail -t -f info@domain.com"
```

This might be improved using regex to extract the `From` field directly from the original message, plus deleting the `msg_id_in_queue` thereafter, but for the use I needed, this was enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can set in the transport file `/etc/postfix/transport` a line like this:

```
* smtp:[new_server_dns_or_ip]
```

Then do:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Then do `postfix reload` to load changes.

Then flush the queue with:

```
postqueue -f
```

If instead of setting `*` you set a domain name, only mails to this domain will be redirected to the new server.

Answer (score 2):

I had a dead server which still had mails in `/var/spool/postfix/{maildrop,defer,deferred}/`. I was able to just copy the files into the right places on a working server. This is how:

- Move disk containing /var from dead server to working server, and mount it. In this example, /var was a separate partition, and it's mounted at `/mnt/old_var/`
- Set correct permissions on the files (in case UIDs are different):

```
chown -R postfix:postdrop /mnt/old_var/spool/postfix/maildrop
chown -R postfix:postfix  /mnt/old_var/spool/postfix/defer*
```

- Move maildrop files

`mv /mnt/old_var/spool/postfix/maildrop/* /var/spool/postfix/maildrop/`

- Move deferred files

```
cd /mnt/old_var/spool/postfix/
find defer -type f -printf "%P\n" \
| while read f; do
    for d in defer deferred; do
      mv -v $d/$f /var/spool/postfix/$d/$f
    done
done
```

or the same last command as a single line:

```
cd /mnt/old_var/spool/postfix/; find defer -type f -printf "%P\n" | while read f; do for d in defer deferred; do mv -v $d/$f /var/spool/postfix/$d/$f; done; done
```